# Proof about sets and their cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let A,B be finite sets. Assume size(A)=size(B) and A$\subseteq$B then A=B.

Proof: Since size(A)=size(B), then there exists a one to one correspondence between the two sets. Assume that A$\neq$B, that means that $\exists$ b$\in$B such that f(a)$\neq$b that means that the function is not surjective, which is a contradiction.

Is this proof correct? Furthermore, is there another way to prove it? Am I correct to say that the same proof works for countable sets?

Comment: The statement is simply wrong for countable sets which are not finite. For example $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ and they have the same cardinality. But they are not equal.

Comment: Oh thanks so much!. That was helpful. Out of curiosity, am I  correct to say that my proof is correct for finite sets?

Comment: It is fine if you really know that it is true that one to one function between two finite sets of the same size is surjective. This is not something absolutely trivial.

Comment: I was mainly thinking of what it means for two sets to have the same size (cardinality). By definition, two sets have the same size if there exists a bijective map between them (one to one correspondence). Hence if I assume A$\neq$B then that means $\exists$ b$\in$B such that f(a)$\neq$b which means that the function is not surjective, hence a contradiction? Can two finite sets have the size but not be bijective?

Comment: @mathsssislife   I like your proof.  :)

Comment: Thanks so much @irchans!

Comment: One to one doesn't mean bijective. As I know a bijective function is a function which is both one and one and onto.

Comment: @Mark, From what I understood, a one to one correspondence does not mean one to one but rather one to one and onto (bijective), am I mistaken?

Comment: @mathsssislife no, you are correct

Comment: Well, maybe there are different definitions. If by bijective you mean one to one and onto then it's fine.

Comment: @Mark. Yes, by bijective I mean one to one and onto.

Comment: @Holo. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Just to comment: people often use "one-to-one **correspondence**" to mean a bijection (so injective and surjective), but "one-to-one" just refers to an injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a one-to-one correspondence, you can just do the following.

Suppose $|A|=|B|$ and $A\subseteq B$. Assume that $A\neq B$. Then there exists $b\in B$ such that $b\not\in A$. But every element of $A$ is in $B$, which implies that $|A|\leq |B|-1$, so $|A|<|B|$, a contradiction.

Comment: That was really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: But do you think my proof is correct?

Comment: It's a bit sloppy. For instance: you don't explicitly say what $f$ is; and you say that because $A\neq B$ there must exist $b$ which is not in the image of $f$ but you don't really explain why this is the case. If you amend these things I think your proof is good.

Comment: How would I say what f is (other than it is a bijective map) if i'm just talking about two arbitrary sets that have the same cardinality and one is a subset of another? No extra information is given, so i'm not sure what to say.

Comment: It's fine that you use the fact that finite sets of the same size have a bijection between them, I'm just saying that you never actually said that that is what $f$ is. So you should say "...then there exists a one-to-one correspondence between the two sets, call it $f$."

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when I said: "Assume that A≠B, that means that ∃ b∈B such that f(a)≠b", this doesn't necessarily mean the bijective map I mentioned earlier, am I right? because this statement just means that there does not exist a surjective map in general, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah you could just show that there exists no surjection $f:A\to B$ which will produce a contradiction.